# How to unbind single use-case in cameraX

Tags: java, android, react-native, kotlin, android-camerax

I have multiple use cases for lens, preview, focus etc

I know how to unbind it all `cameraProvider?.unbindAll()`

But, how to unbind only one use case. How to pass only focus to unbind ?

And how It knows, Which one to unbind if I pass `cameraProvider?.unbind(imageCapture)` because there is no order and they are not assigned to any variable. So, I'm confused !

Each time I unbind all the screen will be reloaded. So, I need to somehow avoid that.

while trying so, I'm also getting this error

```
No supported surface combination is found for camera device - Id : 0. May be attempting to bind too many use cases.
```

Comment: Are you using this as native ui component in RN? what could be potential cause on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64789211/camerax-view-in-react-native-unable-to-configure-camera

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But, how to unbind only one use case

You can unbind only one use case (or even two use cases) using [`ProcessCameraProvider.unbind()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/lifecycle/ProcessCameraProvider#unbind(androidx.camera.core.UseCase...)) which takes a variable number of arguments (varargs) of type `UseCase`.

```
// Binding Preview and ImageCapture use cases
cameraProvider.bind(lifecycleOwner, cameraSelector, preview, imageCapture)

...

// Unbinding the ImageCapture use case
cameraProvider.unbind(imageCapture)
```

> And how It knows, Which one to unbind if I pass
> cameraProvider?.unbind(imageCapture) because there is no order and
> they are not assigned to any variable. So, I'm confused !

CameraX doesn't need to explicitly know that you're unbinding an image capture use case for example. It unbinds a use case, which has a certain configuration, e.g. Surface, resolution, image format, etc. This translates to updating the camera capture session if necessary.

> Each time I unbind all the screen will be reloaded. So, I need to
> somehow avoid that.

The glitch is probably caused by unbinding a repeating capture request, like preview.